# Creating google account using AccountManager is it possible?

Tags: android, account-management

I'm trying to create google account in android I have two questions thanks.

1. Is it possible to add account using "com.google" type account? Because I tried not to create my own Account Authenticator.

   - I always got a "java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10146 is different than the authenticator's uid"
2. If I already have an existing Android Account like ("dmdm425@gmail.com") is it possible to to change or edit its information like changing username and password.

I hope you can answer this question cause Im having hard time resolving this issue.

thank you so much